# ¿Como evito volver a la pantalla de Login una vez logueado en Angular 8?

Tags: angular

Hice una aplicación con un Login, pero una vez me logueo y le doy al botón atrás este vuelve al login  aun teniendo una sesión iniciada, mi pregunta es ¿como puedo evitar esto? ya que soy nuevo en Angular.

Este es mi Guard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GuardAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor( private auth: AuthService, private router: Router ) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.auth.authentication()) {
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: En React JS lo manejo de la siguiente forma, no creo que sea tan diferente la lógica... creo un componente que me indique si mi usuario actual esta logeado o no, ¿como se si esta logeado? en mi caso por los JWT que guarda en el localStorage, sessionStorage o Cookies, dentro de ese componente hago la logica de las rutas usando mi componente Route (en angular no se que componente es...) si el usuario esta logeado sigue el flujo normal en  caso contrario se hace un Redirect hacia la pagina de inicio, login o simil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor que podés hacer es implementar un segundo Guard, pero solo para el `LoginComponent` que, como ya lo tenés en tu Guard, detecte si ya estás logeado.

Si estás logeado: redirigir a la pagina principal. En este caso podría ser un Dashboard o lo que deseas que se muestre al iniciar la sesión.